# How to fix error when attempting to publish Azure artifact?

Tags: azure

When attempting to publish artifacts for an Azure pipeline with `az artifacts universal publish` command, I get this error (some confidential info in square brackets):

```
Encountered an unexpected error.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as [user] in a web browser to enable access to the service.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.CreateDataProviderAsync(String location, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.ExceptionExtensions.ReThrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ArtifactTool.DedupManifestArtifactClientProvider.GetDedupManifestArtifactClientAsync(String serviceUrl, String patVar, ILogger commandBaseLogger, IAppTraceSource tracer, String cacheDirectory, Boolean cacheWriteAllowed, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Providers\DedupManifestArtifactClient\DedupManifestArtifactClientProvider.cs:line 56
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackPublishCommand.ExecuteAsync() in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\UPack\UPackPublishCommand.cs:line 51
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.CommandBase.OnExecuteAsync() in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\CommandBase.cs:line 105
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 77
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 62
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.<OnExecute>b__0() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 505
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 611
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 57
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 145
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](IConsole console, String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 130
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 112
Process ['/Users/jelle/.azure/azuredevops/cli/tools/artifacttool/ArtifactTool_osx-x64_0.2.300/artifacttool', 'universal', 'publish', '--service', 'https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/', '--patvar', 'AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_ARTIFACTTOOL_PATVAR', '--feed', '[organization]', '--package-name', '[package-name]', '--package-version', '[version]', '--path', '[path.dmg]', '--project', '[project'] with PID 38208 exited with return code 1
```

I've tried various things like az logout, az login, clear my azure cache. I also waited a few weeks in case this was an Azure server issue. None of this worked.

How can I fix this?

Best,

Jelle